# Disable multiple values in dropdowns based on another dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want disable multiple values in the second and third dropdown based on first dropdown selected values.I am able to do this for single selected value.But,How to do  this for multiple selected values.

I have 3 drop downs and all are multi select drop downs.
My code is,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        var $dropdown1 = $("select[name='project_manager[]']");
        var $dropdown2 = $("select[name='test_engineer[]']");
        var $dropdown3 = $("select[name='viewer[]']");

        $dropdown1.change(function() {
            $dropdown2.empty().append($dropdown1.find('option').clone());
            $dropdown3.empty().append($dropdown2.find('option').clone());
            var selectedItem = $(this).val();
            if (selectedItem) {
                $dropdown2.find('option[value="' + selectedItem + '"]').prop('disabled', true);
                $dropdown3.find('option[value="' + selectedItem + '"]').prop('disabled', true);
            }
        });

        $dropdown2.change(function() {
            $dropdown3.empty().append($dropdown2.find('option').clone());
            var selectedItem = $(this).val();
            if (selectedItem) {
                $dropdown3.find('option[value="' + selectedItem + '"]').prop('disabled', true);
            }
        });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <select name="project_manager[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">Test 2</option>
  <option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>

<select name="test_engineer[]" multiple="multiple" >
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">Test 2</option>
  <option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>
<select name="viewer[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">Test 2</option>
  <option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>
  <script>
    // tell the embed parent frame the height of the content
    if (window.parent && window.parent.parent){
      window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
        height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
        slug: "vrLr9wyg"
      }], "*")
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to disable a value or the entire dropdown? There's a difference

Comment: I want to disable the values

Comment: Could you please provide JSfiddle link?

Comment: [You already asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51284110/jquery-disable-function-is-not-working-with-jquery-other-code-for-dropdown). This looks like a generic javascript problem to me. You should consider having a basic mastery of [how to use debugger console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   if (selectedItem) {

    $(selectedItem).each(function(v,i) {

    $dropdown2.find('option[value="' + i + '"]').prop('disabled', true);

    $dropdown3.find('option[value="' + i + '"]').prop('disabled', true);

                                });
```

Comment: I updated my answer. jquery function reference for  [link] (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each)

Comment: When I add css to the dropdown the above functionality will not working.