# jquery disable function is not working with jquery other code for dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to to disable drop downs values based on one drop down.I am able to do this.But I want to add search button and checkbox for multi select,when I add that,disable functionality is not working.Where it is going wrong I didn't understand.How can I solve this?

My code is without adding css and js another than disable code,

```js
//Script from the first script tag.

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#project_manager').multiselect({
    nonSelectedText: 'Select project_manager',
    enableFiltering: true,
    enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
    buttonWidth: '400px'
  });

  $('#test_engineer').multiselect({
    nonSelectedText: 'Select test_engineer',
    enableFiltering: true,
    enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
    buttonWidth: '400px'
  });
  $('#viewer').multiselect({
    nonSelectedText: 'Select test_engineer',
    enableFiltering: true,
    enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
    buttonWidth: '400px'
  });
});


//Script from the second script tag.
$(window).load(function() {
  var $dropdown1 = $("select[name='project_manager[]']");
  var $dropdown2 = $("select[name='test_engineer[]']");
  var $dropdown3 = $("select[name='viewer[]']");

  $dropdown1.change(function() {
    $dropdown2.empty().append($dropdown1.find('option').clone());
    $dropdown3.empty().append($dropdown2.find('option').clone());
    var selectedItem = $(this).val();
    if (selectedItem) {
      $(selectedItem).each(function(v, selectedItem) {
        $dropdown2.find('option[value="' + selectedItem + '"]').prop('disabled', true);
        $dropdown3.find('option[value="' + selectedItem + '"]').prop('disabled', true);
      });
    }
  });

  $dropdown2.change(function() {
    $dropdown3.empty().append($dropdown2.find('option').clone());
    var selectedItem = $(this).val();
    if (selectedItem) {
      $(selectedItem).each(function(v, selectedItem) {
        $dropdown3.find('option[value="' + selectedItem + '"]').prop('disabled', true);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Webslesson Tutorial | Bootstrap Multi Select Dropdown with Checkboxes using Jquery in PHP</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" />

</head>

<body>
  <select id="project_manager" name="project_manager[]" multiple class="form-control">
    <option value="Codeigniter">Codeigniter</option>
    <option value="CakePHP">CakePHP</option>
    <option value="Laravel">Laravel</option>
    <option value="YII">YII</option>
    <option value="Zend">Zend</option>
    <option value="Symfony">Symfony</option>
    <option value="Phalcon">Phalcon</option>
    <option value="Slim">Slim</option>

  </select>
  <select id="test_engineer" name="test_engineer[]" multiple class="form-control">
    <option value="Codeigniter">Codeigniter</option>
    <option value="CakePHP">CakePHP</option>
    <option value="Laravel">Laravel</option>
    <option value="YII">YII</option>
    <option value="Zend">Zend</option>
    <option value="Symfony">Symfony</option>
    <option value="Phalcon">Phalcon</option>
    <option value="Slim">Slim</option>
  </select>
  <select id="viewer" name="viewer[]" multiple class="form-control">
    <option value="Codeigniter">Codeigniter</option>
    <option value="CakePHP">CakePHP</option>
    <option value="Laravel">Laravel</option>
    <option value="YII">YII</option>
    <option value="Zend">Zend</option>
    <option value="Symfony">Symfony</option>
    <option value="Phalcon">Phalcon</option>
    <option value="Slim">Slim</option>

  </select>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why do you keep asking this question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51278132/disable-multiple-values-in-dropdowns-based-on-another-dropdown

Comment: @Adelin, I am able to add disable functionality but while adding css and js why it won't work? Can you assist me to get the reason for this?

Comment: why do you have multiple ready functions? why is your script outside the HTML tag? and where is you css adding function?

Comment: @Ullass , I have edited.But still it is not working.

Comment: why do you have multiple `<script>` tags right below each other?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script> link is missed  in the above code

Comment: I kept in the same <script > also it won't work

Comment: I have many ways.No one is useful.How can I solve the  problem?

Comment: This looks like a generic javascript problem to me. You should consider having a basic mastery of [how to use debugger console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/)